# Select where pivvot has both records

Tags: sqlite

Sqlite 3.22.0

I have these tables: `users`, `book`, `user_books`. I'm trying to select a book, which belongs to certain users only (users with id 3 and 5 in the example below):

```
select * from books
inner join user_books ub on books.id = ub.book_id
where ub.user_id in (3, 5)
```

`user_books` data:

```
user_id | book_id
      1 |       1
      2 |       2
      3 |       3
      4 |       4
      5 |       5
      3 |       5
```

I expect to get book with id 5, but I'm getting book with id 3 and 5.

What's wrong?

I've tried

```
select * from books
inner join user_books ub on books.id = ub.book_id
where ub.user_id = 3 and ub.user_id = 5
```

but got empty result.

Comment: I want to add that in your second query, the condition `ub.user_id = 3 and ub.user_id = 5` is necessary false, because `ub.user_id` can not be equal to 3 *and* 5 at once, it's contradictory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must join the 2 tables, `group by b.id` and use `having count(*) = 2`, so that you get only the books that belong to both users:

```
select b.id 
from books b inner join user_books u
on u.book_id = b.id
where u.user_id in (3, 5)
group by b.id
having count(*) = 2
```